# CSS: error at "min-width"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, eclipse, angular-ui-bootstrap

There's an error at `@media (min-width: 564px)` and the next line:

[image: If you see the image there's an error at the @media (min-width: 564px)and its next line]

I am new to this and CSS and I do not understand the error. Can anyone suggest what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this code i think this code will help you.

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
  here your code .....
}/*mobile device */

@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px){
  here your code .....
}/*mobile device */

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px){
  here your code .....
}/*ipad  device */

Answer (score 0):

It should be like 
`@media screen and (min-width: 564px)`